# Apple Match-O-Linker Error for MapKit ['Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386]

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, i386

The following symbol(s) do not seem to be interpreted successfully in Xcode5. In addition, I added each specific header to both the interface and implementation; after searching the location of each symbol, but it still singles them out as undefined after re-running my program. Any help is appreciated.

```
    distanceFilterDidChange:
    locationDidChange:
    mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:
    boundingMapRect:
```

Comment: Are you referencing the right SDK's. You may be adding them to your files but did you reference it within Xcode

Comment: Thank you for responding, I'm very sorry, I don't believe I understand your question. I've referenced all libraries on both 'interface' and 'implementation' files; All SDK's were added previously. I was able to run the same script on the deprecated edition of Xcode, not so lucky after upgrading. Should I add all binaries again, or check that they have been added successfully? Thanks again.

Comment: Did you include the acutal MapKit Library to your xcode project? You can well include all the headers of the world and the code will compile fine. But without the libraries included the linker cannot match the symbols to any pice of machine code.

Comment: thats what I was trying to say @HermannKlecker

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing ... As you guys had pointed out, the MapKit Framework was not Linked to the actual project! Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Where exactly did you add them? Including header files to both, interface and implementation (one of them would do anyway) is not what I am talking about. Did you add the library to your target's build phase? (Link Binaries with Libraries)

Comment: All right. Glad you found it. Cheers

Comment: Hey guys, I'm able to compile the source code, but it returns a 'black screen'. Everything runs smoothly, except for 'a few' warnings; Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong this time?